# How to make log in function without using email

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna ask how to make the login function just using a password. for the email just use the current email. Basically, I want to log in function in the app. because I want to do the delete the account function, but when the user wants to delete the account, you must log in again to proceed with it. but I want the user just input the password. for email just use the current user email for it.

Comment: Why don't you just show a dialog to prompt for the password?

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need to persist the users email on the app in order to pass in as a param on thier behalf. There are multiple ways of doing this including stored preferences and local storage. Based on the field you might want to encrypt it while stored.